# (ionic) How to debug SQLite on browser without android/ios simulator

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm new in ionic. I try to read the console log about successful execution on browser but it always show "Cannot read property 'executeSql' of undefined". Can anyone suggest the effective method to debug the project?

```
    if (!this.isOpen) 
    {
      this.storage = new SQLite();
      this.storage.create(
        {
          name:"data.db",
          location:"default"
        })
      .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
        this.db = db;
        db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, identification INTEGER, name TEXT, lastname text)", {})
        this.isOpen = true;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }


 GetAllUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM users", [])
      .then((data) => {
        let arrayUsers = [];
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            arrayUsers.push({
              id: data.rows.item(i).id,
              identification: data.rows.item(i).identification, 
              name: data.rows.item(i).name, 
              lastname: data.rows.item(i).lastname
            });
          }
        }
        resolve(arrayUsers);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: console logs....?

Comment: where are you initializing `this.db`? You can debug this by console logs in your browser dev tools

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put initializing code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `this.db` dosen't conatins the instance of WebSQL.

```
this.db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

You need to initialize the connection to db first and then use.

If already initialized, make sure the variable is scoped properly and is accessible inside  `GetAllUsers()`, or reopen the connection using `openDatabase` inside the function. (Though, its never recommended to open db connections inside every function)

```
this.db = openDatabase('dbName', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
this.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM users", []).then(() => {} );
```

[image]

Comment: it can't find 'openDatabase' method

Comment: Is it giving error on console ? Show code ..